# Second derivative test, what if f ''(x) = 0

Tags: derivatives

Let  $f(x)$ be a differentiable function. If $( 0, 0)$ is a local minimum of the graph of 
$y = f(x)$, which of the following may be true?

$(1) f '(0) = 0$

$(2) f '(0) > 0$

$(4) f "(0) = 0$

$(8) f "(0) > 0$

Would (4) be correct when the degree of x in  $f''(x)$ is $0$ ? ( such that the second derivative test is not applicable in testing whether a point is minimum or maximum )
Btw, I think that (1) and (8) are correct.

Comment: For $4$, consider $f(x)=x^4$

Comment: Sorry to go OT, but more than one answer may be correct, yes? For a second, I found the numbering scheme a bit odd, but then I realised it's rather clever - a binary encoding, with possible sums ranging from 1 to 15, with the sum corresponding to a unique combination of choices. Right? To answer your specific question, the option with value 4 can indeed be correct, and @saulspatz has given a good example.So the correct answer would be 1 + 4 + 8 = 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f’(0) = 0 \iff$ there is a stationary point at $x=0$.

$f’’(0) = 0 $ doesn’t really tell us anything. There could be a minimum or a maximum, or something else, at this point. As *saulspatz* says, take $f(x) = x^4$ as an example of a function that has a minimum at $x=0$ and $f’’(x) = 0$.

$f’(0) = 0, f’’(0) > 0 \implies$ there is a local minimum at $x=0$.

So, to answer your question, **(1)** is true since local minimum at $x=0$ $\implies f’(0) = 0$, and **(8)** is not true since the implication only goes the other way. Given that the function has a minimum at $x=0$, we can’t deduce that the second derivative there is positive.

However, you ask: ‘which of the following *may* be true?’. It is *possible* for **(4)** and **(8)** to be true, but it isn’t implied by the information we have. So we have that **(1)**, **(4)** and, **(8)** are possible in this case. Note that **(2)** is not possible since there being a stationary point implies that the first derivative is zero at that point.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be $n$ times differentiable at $x$ and suppose$$f'(x)=f''(x)=\dots=f^{(n-1)}(x)=0$$ Then if $f^{(n)}(x)>0$ there is a local minimum at $x$ and if $f^{(n)}(x)<0$ there is a local maximum at $x$.  This is easy to see by considering the Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $x$.  If you haven't learned about Taylor polynomials yet, come back and read this again when you do, and you'll see it's very simple.  In the meantime, $f(x)=x^n$ gives examples of this behavior for all $n$.

If $f$ is infinitely differentiable at $x$, and $$f^{(k)}(x)=0,\ k=1,2,3,\dots$$ then nothing can be said.  You might have a local minim, a local maximum, or neither.